# How can we check key exists in dictionary after converting data-type (dtype)?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary `d`.
I am allowing the user to input any potential dictionary key.

Some pseudo-code is provided below for the behavior I want:

```
key = get_user_input()

if the key is present in dictionary `d`, then
    print, "key exists"
else
    print that the key does not exist.
```

The dictionary is:

```python
d = {
    'country' : 'India',
    123:[11,22],
    12.5:(33,44),
    (55,66): {8,9},
    'pincode' :{12:'java'}
}
```

My python code is as follows:

```python
k = input()
    
if k in d.keys():
    print("key exists and value is", d[k])
```

The user's input is always a string.
I am not sure what data-type the user is trying to input.

Suppose that we know that the user input a tuple.
Then, we could write `tuple(map(int, input))`

However, the user can also enter an integer as input, not just a tuple.

Comment: convert the input to your dictionary key type. If your key is string, then. convert input to string and compare. What is your question and desired output? Looks like your `if k in d.keys()` will work for the dict `d`

Comment: my desired out is  `("key exists and value is", d[k])`, if the user give input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would normally recommend that all keys be set to the same datatype. However, if you do have a situation where a predefined dictionary comes with varying datatype, then you have to brute force and check for the keys.

Here's how I got through it.

```
d={'country' : 'India', 123:[11,22], 12.5:(33,44),
   (55,66): {8,9}, (55,'a'): {'b','c'},
   ("a",55): {'p','q'}, ("a",'b'): {'x','y'},
   'pincode' :{12:'java'}}
k = input()
if k in d.keys():
    print ('key exists and value is', d[k])
elif k.isnumeric() and int(k) in d.keys():
   print ('key exists and value is', d[int(k)])
elif len(k.split(',')) == 2:
    y = k.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace('"','').replace("'",'').split(',')
    y[0] = int(y[0]) if y[0].isnumeric() else y[0]
    y[1] = int(y[1]) if y[1].isnumeric() else y[1]
    z = (y[0],y[1])
    if z in d.keys():
        print ('key exists and value is', d[z])
else:
    try:
        float(k)
        if float(k) in d.keys():
            print ('key exists and value is', d[float(k)])
    except:
        pass
```

Output of this is as follows:

```
country
key exists and value is India

123
key exists and value is [11, 22]

12.5
key exists and value is (33, 44)

(55,66)
key exists and value is {8, 9}

55,66
key exists and value is {8, 9}

(55,'a')
key exists and value is {'c', 'b'}

(55,"a")
key exists and value is {'c', 'b'}

('a',55)
key exists and value is {'q', 'p'}

('a','b')
key exists and value is {'x', 'y'}

'a','b'
key exists and value is {'x', 'y'}

a,b
key exists and value is {'x', 'y'}

("a",55)
key exists and value is {'p', 'q'}

a,55
key exists and value is {'q', 'p'}
```

For the below items, it didn't print any.

```
45
state
124
17.5
(50,50)
(55,66,66)
```

Comment: your code is goood, but its not generalize, if i enter tuple with length 3 and inside any str is present it wont work

Comment: added the code to take in just tuple inputs like `55,66` without `(` and `)`

Comment: can you give me an example of a tuple you tried please?

Comment: d={'country' : 'India', 123:[11,22], 12.5:(33,44), (55,'a'): {8,9}, 'pincode' :{12:'java'}}

Comment: good point. I need to figure out how to get the tuple value so we can get the key from the dict.

Comment: @sim, solved for that as well. The only condition for which I haven't solved are the following : `55,a`, `55,'a'`, `a,55`, `'a',55`,`a,b`,`'a','b'`. Working on fixing them as well

Comment: @sim, solved for all options. Let me know if there is a scenario that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason the keys in the dictionary must be floats/tuples? Why not change to:

```
d={'country':'India',
   '123':[11,22], 
   '12.5':(33,44), 
   '(55,66)':{8,9}, 
   'pincode':{12:'java'}
}
```

This should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're seeking?

```
d = {
    'country' : 'India',
    123:[11,22],
    12.5:(33,44),
    (55,66): {8,9},
    'pincode' :{12:'java'}
}
x = '(55, 66)'
if x in str(d.keys()): print(True)

# output
# >>> True
```

Note:

Additional formatting is needed for the input like adding space after a comma.
`(55,66)` needs to reformat into `(55, 66)` because the key type is 'tuple' for `(55,66)` key